# How to add a class, if there is no sub-categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

If category empty, add to class "empty". 
I have this code.

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categoryId = 3;?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ?>
<?php $_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>

<div class="catalog-menu">
    <ul class="multi-accordion">
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li class="roll">
                <a class="roll-link1" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php if($_category->hasChildren()):?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <ul class="headline">
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li class="roll">
                                <a class="roll-link2" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                                <?php $_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                                <?php if($_category2->hasChildren()):?>
                                <?php $_subcategories2 = $_category2->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                    <ul class="headline">
                                        <?php foreach($_subcategories2 as $_subcategory2): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a class="roll-link3" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory2) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory2->getName() ?></a>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `count($_subcategories)<1`  or  `count($_subcategories2)<1` for `getting the categories whose does have  no sub-categories`.

also you can use

```
 if(!$_category->hasChildren()):

if(!$_category2->hasChildren()):
```

you can try this:

```
<?php $_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>

<div class="catalog-menu">
    <ul class="multi-accordion">
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li class="roll">
             <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                 <a class="roll-link1 <?php if(!$_category->hasChildren()):?> empty <?php endif; ?>" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>

                <?php if($_category->hasChildren()):?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <ul class="headline">
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>

                         <?php $_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                            <li class="roll  <?php if(!$_category2->hasChildren()):?> emtpty <?php endif;?>"  >
                                <a class="roll-link2" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></a>

                                <?php if($_category2->hasChildren()):?>
                                <?php $_subcategories2 = $_category2->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                    <ul class="headline">
                                        <?php foreach($_subcategories2 as $_subcategory2): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a class="roll-link3" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory2) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory2->getName() ?></a>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think it's not appropriate. How will change class? In your case, if there are sub-categories, they will not be displayed?

Comment: in which html element i want to add class `empty`

Comment: getChildrenCategories &  getChildrenAmount give  only active sub categories

Comment: Does not work. Lost menu.:-(

Comment: I will check...